# How do I make a variable function in a class in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have a class like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def call(self,instruction,data):
        pass

    def handle_foo(self,data):
        print "Foo: %s" % data

    def handle_bar(self,data):
        print "%s: bar" % data
```

And code calling it like:

```
t = Test()
t.call("foo","abc")
t.call("bar","def")
```

How do I make the call definition call the functions by inserting the variable "instruction" in the function name?

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
def call(self,instruction,data):
    func = "self.handle_%s" % instruction
    func(data)
```

Comment: You could just pass the actual function as a parameter, too. Functions are objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) to get a member of an object with the member's name as a string.

```
getattr(self, 'handle_' + instruction)(data)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! I'll accept once the anti-bot timer is done ticking down.

Answer (score 2):

That would be using the getattr method

```
func = getattr(self, 'handle_%s' % instruction)
func(data)
```